# dc and standard input or heredoc with string command?

Tags: shell, here-document, dc

`dc` can read command from a file or/and from standard input.
If I want to print user input :

```
cat essai_dc
[enter a number : ]
n
?
p

dc essai_dc 
  enter a number : 4
  4
```

Now, if I try with a `heredoc` :

```
dc <<EOF
> [enter a number : ]
> n
> ?
> p
> EOF  

enter a number : dc: stack empty
```

I get the same with standard input :

```
cat essai_dc | dc
enter a number : dc: stack empty
```

The command ? get the `p` and execute it but the stack is empty.
Is it possible to get it to work (tell `dc` to wait for the input)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?` gets its input from standard input which is the here document  here. You'd need to feed the script to `dc` using a different file descriptor. On systems with `/dev/fd/n`, that  could be with:

```
dc /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'
[enter a number : ]
n
?
p
EOF
```

Or you can use ksh-style process substitution (which generally uses `/dev/fd/n` underneath):

```
dc <(cat << 'EOF'
[enter a number : ]
n
?
p
EOF
)
```

Or doing away with the here-document and the call to the (generally) external `cat` utility:

```
dc <(printf %s \
'[enter a number : ]
n
?
p
'
)
```

Some `dc` implementations like GNU `dc` allow passing the contents of the `dc` script as argument with `-e`, so you could use command substitution:

```
dc -e "$(cat << 'EOF'
[enter a number : ]
n
?
p
EOF
)"
```

Or directly:

```
dc -e '[enter a number : ]
n
?
p'
```

Comment: With the -e option, there is no need of heredoc and command substitution.

Comment: @ctac_, True. I had assumed the OP wanted to use a heredoc (for instance because it allows to specify arbitrary text without having to worry about quoting), but that was interpolation on my part. See edit.